# Binding an image from a view to a new window (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, binding

So in a user controler view called (image.xaml), first i am using a button to start an "openfiledialog" and open the file explorer.

this code is from image.xaml.cs

```
        private void btnimage1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
            btnimage1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        }
    }
```

i then choose an image and then i create a "mouse down" action for that image to open that image in a NEW window. the editimagewindow.xaml has a grid and i want it to show up in that grid section only.

this code is from the image.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnimage1" Content="1" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{DynamicResource btnRounded}" Margin="5" Click="btnimage1_Click"></Button>

                    <Image x:Name="img1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                       Source="{Binding SelectedImage}" MouseDown="img1_MouseDown" />
```

this is from the image.xaml.cs

```
        private void img1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        EditImageWindow edit =  new EditImageWindow();
        edit.Show();

        edit.mainimage.DataContext = img1.DataContext;
        
        edit.mainimage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("SelectedImage"));
        edit.Show();
    }
```

i am using views and viewmodels.

im having trouble working out the binding for the image on the second window. i cant get the image to show at all. i just started using WPF about a week ago so im not exactly sure how to use data context and if i have to use a datatemplate in some sort of usercontrol/window resource.

this code is from the "editimagewindow.xaml"

```
            <Image x:Name="mainimage" Source="{Binding SelectedImage}"
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Comment: What is SelectedImage supposed to be? `Source="{Binding SelectedImage}"` or `new Binding("SelectedImage")` only makes sense when there is an object in the current DataContext that has a public SelectedImage property.

Comment: that's also a part im trying to work out... its not actually anything, I had initially thought it would be binded by name. im not sure how to use data context for this instant @Clemens

Comment: "*its not actually anything*" - then `mainimage.SetBinding` will obviously not work. As said, there must be an object with a SelectedImage property in the DataContext. Right now, the DataContext is just null. It's unclear why you want to set a Binding at all, when `edit.mainimage.Source = img1.Source;` would be sufficient. Besides that, start reading here: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0).

Comment: @clemens i understand more on data contexts now and also thank you that bit of code ended up working.